# How to write IF statement in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating rectangles in svg and then I want to check each rectangle by using its unique id using d3.js. How to check if a rectangle has id "0"?

I tried this following code but it is giving an error.

```
if(d3.select(".rect").attr("id")=="0")
```

Is this format correct? Please help.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve but an easy way to select an element with an id of 0 would be `select("#id=0")`. Although you should avoid id starting with numbers and id that are just numbers.  You may also want to look at this [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) page and this [Bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/464c92429ac05c6a19a1).

Comment: IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: General note: add more context to your questions, use Jsfiddle.